# ImportError: No module named 'googlevoice'

Tags: python, google-voice

python noob here. Just start picking up python few weeks ago and currently need some help. I have 3.3.4 python for windows 7 and I tried running this:

```
    import urllib.request
    from googlevoice import Voice
    from googlevoice.util import input
    import time
 File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
 from googlevoice import Voice
 ImportError: No module named 'googlevoice'
```

so I figured. no big deal, I just need to install the module. I obtained a setup.py file from the link below and ran the file in different directories. Then tried " import googlevoice" but still doesn't work. The github link isn't too helpful, in terms of installing this module. Please help? I think I just have not learned how to install modules properly. Last time it took me a while to install pygame module, but i think it was because of directory issues at first.

https://pygooglevoice.googlecode.com/hg/

http://sphinxdoc.github.io/pygooglevoice/examples.html

Comment: Have you tried using easy_install as it says [here](http://sphinxdoc.github.io/pygooglevoice/install.html#setups)?

Comment: Have you installed pygooglevoice yet?

Answer (score 1):

To install the PyGoogleVoice, you need to download the whole archive and execute:

```
python setup.py install
```

If you have *pip* install, you can also run `pip install pygooglevoice`, or `easy_install pygooglevoice` with *EasyInstall*, without having to download the source code.

Comment: IT says "some externally hosted files were ignored"